# Plist XPath query with dict elements

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to load song names from an iTunes library export of a plist via Nokigiri:

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(file.path))

```
@songs = Array.new  
doc.xpath(<XPATH_HERE>).each do |n|
  @songs.push(n)  #append data to array
end
```

The beginning of the plist looks like:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
  <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
  <key>Date</key><date>2014-10-15T22:52:19Z</date>
  <key>Application Version</key><string>11.4</string>
  <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
  <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
  <key>Music Folder</key><string>file://localhost/Users/mike/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/</string>
  <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>280B84572DDCF406</string>
  <key>Tracks</key>
  <dict>
    <key>96</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Track ID</key><integer>96</integer>
      <key>Name</key><string>Get Lucky (Daft Punk cover)</string>
      <key>Artist</key><string>Daughter</string>
      <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
      <key>Size</key><integer>4716638</integer>
      <key>Total Time</key><integer>294112</integer>
      <key>Date Modified</key><date>2013-11-12T20:54:14Z</date>
      <key>Date Added</key><date>2013-12-18T17:56:09Z</date>
      <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>128</integer>
      <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
      <key>Persistent ID</key><string>C3B1B6F26134C9C1</string>
      <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
      <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/Users/mike/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Daughter/Unknown%20Album/Get%20Lucky%20(Daft%20Punk%20cover).mp3</string>
      <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>5</integer>
      <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>98</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Track ID</key><integer>98</integer>
      <key>Name</key><string>Swimming in Solace (DJ Fergie Ferg Remash)</string>
      <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
```

What I am looking to load from each track is the track name string that comes after the name key. The XPath that I thought should work is

```
/plist/dict[key[. = 'Tracks']/following-sibling::*[1]]/dict[key/following-sibling::*[1]]/dict[key[. = 'Name']/following-sibling::*[1]]/string
```

That XPath returns:

```
<string>Get Lucky (Daft Punk cover)</string>
<string>Daughter</string>
<string>MPEG audio file</string>
<string>C3B1B6F26134C9C1</string>
<string>File</string>
<string>file://localhost/Users/mike/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Daughter/Unknown%20Album/Get%20Lucky%20(Daft%20Punk%20cover).mp3</string>
<string>Swimming in Solace (DJ Fergie Ferg Remash)</string>
<string>MPEG audio file</string>
```

It seems that, although my XPath is specifying the key for each string, it is in fact taking the 'following-siblings' of all of each dict regardless.

What can I do to make the query more specific so that this portion of the plist would return:

```
Get Lucky (Daft Punk cover)
```

and

```
Swimming in Solace (DJ Fergie Ferg Remash)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one possible XPath :

```
/plist/dict[key='Tracks']/dict/dict/key[.='Name']/following-sibling::string[1]
```

The beginning of the XPath may varies, but I think the most important part is the last 2 path steps (`key[.='Name']/following-sibling::string[1]`). It tell to get the closest `<string>` element after every `<key>Name</key>` element.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought I was going crazy trying different permutations.
Just as a note, adding `/node()` to the end of the xpath that you provided will remove the `<string>` tags as well and just get the string value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
      <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
      <key>Date</key><date>2014-10-15T22:52:19Z</date>
      <key>Application Version</key><string>11.4</string>
      <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
      <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
      <key>Music Folder</key><string>file://localhost/Users/mike/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/</string>
      <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>280B84572DDCF406</string>
      <key>Tracks</key>
      <dict>
        <key>96</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Track ID</key><integer>96</integer>
          <key>Name</key><string>Get Lucky (Daft Punk cover)</string>
          <key>Artist</key><string>Daughter</string>
          <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
          <key>Size</key><integer>4716638</integer>
          <key>Total Time</key><integer>294112</integer>
          <key>Date Modified</key><date>2013-11-12T20:54:14Z</date>
          <key>Date Added</key><date>2013-12-18T17:56:09Z</date>
          <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>128</integer>
          <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
          <key>Persistent ID</key><string>C3B1B6F26134C9C1</string>
          <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
          <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/Users/mike/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Daughter/Unknown%20Album/Get%20Lucky%20(Daft%20Punk%20cover).mp3</string>
          <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>5</integer>
          <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>98</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Track ID</key><integer>98</integer>
          <key>Name</key><string>Swimming in Solace (DJ Fergie Ferg Remash)</string>
          <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
EOT
```

With that setup, the code is:

```
doc.search('dict dict dict').map{ |d| d.at('./key[2]').next_sibling.text }
# => ["Get Lucky (Daft Punk cover)",
#     "Swimming in Solace (DJ Fergie Ferg Remash)"]
```

I much prefer using CSS selectors where possible, and Nokogiri doesn't care whether we use them or XPath against XML content, hence the use of `search('dict dict dict')`. Then, XPath makes it convenient to grab the nth-element, which lead to using `at('./key[2]')` to grab the `<key>` node. `next_sibling` then returns the next node.

It's possible to do it in pure XPath, but I find that looking like line-noise, and prefer this mixed approach. The pure XPath might run faster, but I'd be able to maintain my way faster.